# python asyncio as_completed SIGINT doubts

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sigint

After quite some reading on asyncio (I'm totally noob about it), I've managed to write simple programs that do what I want them to do.

Yet, I have some dobuts regarding as_completed method: how should I handle SIGINT signal properly.

So, let there be the following snippet:

```
#as_completed_example.py
import asyncio
import tqdm
import datetime
import sys
import signal
import random
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def heavy_load(i):
    #tqdm.tqdm.write('#DEBUG    '+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+' '+str(i))
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
    return None
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def main():
    length  =   int(sys.argv[1])
    inputs  =   list(range(length))
    pbar    =   tqdm.tqdm(total=len(inputs),position=0,leave=True,bar_format='#PROGRESS {desc}: {percentage:.3f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}')
    tasks   =   [heavy_load(i) for i in inputs]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        _ = await future
        pbar.update(1)
        pbar.refresh()            
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
def sigint_handler(signum,frame):
    tqdm.tqdm.write('#INFO '+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+' user aborted execution!')
    sys.exit(0)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
if(__name__=='__main__'):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,sigint_handler)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If you call it as `python3 as_completed_example.py 10000 (large number)`, progress bar is stucked at 0.00% for quite some time, while asyncio.as_completed is preparing its input arguments. That's ok.

But, if you send a SIGINT while progressbar is stucked at 0.00%, you get plenty of unhandled exceptions.

How should I modify my code to be able to catch them?

Thanks in advance!!